# Как вывести произвольный текст перед конкретным html-тегом?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть html-код который выводится через переменную $text в шаблоне моего сайта!
В `$text` нужно найти 5-й по счету абзац `<p>...</p>` и добавить перед ним `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>`.

Как это реализовать? Помогите пожалуйста! Пыталась сделать на php, ничего не вышло, так как, мягко говоря, не сильна в этом. Очень нужно решение! Похоже задача несложная, но то, что удалось найти, адаптировать для своих нужд не вышло! Спасибо!

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то ты можешь создать событие `DOMContentLoaded` на `document`.В php, создай заранее абзац, который тебе нужно вставить и дай ему какой-то `id`, который ты будешь использовать чтоб найти его через js и добавляешь в него нужный текст. Естественно добавления текста и поиск нужного абзаца делай внутри события `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: RomanMitasov Спасибо. Но я работаю с шаблоном для того, чтобы не пришлось вносить правки через пользоватеский интерфейс. Нужно добавить именно сам элемент перед определенным элементом по счету! На странице может быть разное количество html элементов.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p:eq(4)').before('<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>');
```

Comment: дебочка не может ни в js ни в php, а ты ей кидаешь jquery без комментария, что его хотя бы нужно подключить, ну тупа парень загадка, увожаю

Comment: спасибо большое! В том виде, что Вы предоставили все работает! Но у меня вопрос как адаптировать код если вместо `Lorem ipsum...` у меня  `<ins>...</ins> <script>...</script>`